# All text box have same Id and i want to write some text in second text box

Tags: selenium

In Selenium we have three `Text` boxes. All the text boxes have the same `Id`, and I want to write some text in the second text box. However, we don't use any locators, and also xpath, so we can only use `id`. How do we resolve this?

Comment: Can u post your url..or html code?

Comment: You should give more details: part of target `html`, which programming language you use, what have you already tried... Also, what you mean "we don't use any locator"? `By.Id` it is a locator

Comment: If you have same id's for all textboxes, then use some other identifier like xpath,css_selector or class name etc. post ur html code.\

Comment: Ok but i am thinking to use only id.there is many option to do this we can take xpath also but i want to use only id.is it possible with id?and possible so how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use index value in xpath/css like

> //input[@id='textBoxId'][1]

Or else fetch all the text-boxes in a List then retrieve the 2nd text-box like (Java version)-

> List< WebElement> webLocators = driver.findElements(By.id('textBoxId'));
>
> webLocators[1].sendKeys("xyz");

Comment: That Xpath is not really doing what you think it is doing.  //input[@id='textBoxId'][1] will find all instances of an input element with and id that equals "textBoxId" and is a first child.  If you try to find //input[@id='textBoxId'][2] there is a good chance you won't find anything.  I think you really meant (//input[@id='textBoxId'])[1].  This will find all instances of an input element with and id that equals "textBoxId" and will return the first one that you found.

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
use xpath //xpath-indicator-to-textbox[2]
```

Or

```
 getelements --> then sendkey to elements[1] (2nd element in array)
```

Comment: I don't want to use xpath and any locators . i want to use only By.Id().

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, different elements with the same ID are not even valid HTML. As the ID is the element's identifier, it has to be unique.